# The zoomable listview doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem: my custom listview doesn't scroll before zooming. Zooming working as expected. How I can to fix this problem?

ZoomableListView:

```
public class ZoomableListView extends ListView {

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
private boolean isPagerEnabled;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;

// Pivot point for Scaling
static float gx = 0, gy = 0;

public ZoomableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
}

public ZoomableListView(Context context) {
super(context);
mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
canvas.restore();
}


@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// Save the canvas to set the scaling factor returned from detector
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
    isPagerEnabled = true;
} else {
    isPagerEnabled = false;
}

if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
    mPosX = 0.0f;
    mPosY = 0.0f;
}
canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
final int action = ev.getAction();
mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    // Save the ID of this pointer
    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    invalidate();
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
    final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
    }
    break;
}
}

return true;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

}

Here is the XML of custom listview:

```
<com.android.app.core.view.ZoomableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</com.android.app.core.view.ZoomableListView>
```

Thank's for any answers.

Comment: you are returning true in `onTouchEvent`. This means you have handled the touch event, so the parent won't try to handle it any more.

Comment: sorry, I meant that listview doesn't scroll before zooming

Comment: @ricky this zooms the listview from top left corner. Can we controll this? this should zoom the view from the mid point of two fingers. in short this should zoom the view at the pinch position

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242187/how-to-zoom-list-item-from-center-of-pinch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `super.onTouchEvent(ev);`. I tried this out to confirm it worked:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    ...
```

Comment: You need some polish around the edge detection but it is a very nice class! You should check out my project, [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView). It may help with your edge detection code.

Comment: Another note, in your onScale, you should grab the focus point of the scale, with `detector.getFocusX();` and `detector.getFocusY()`. Then, use that focus point to scale your canvas when you are pinch zooming. This will make the view appear to scale more naturally.

Comment: Thanks, I added detector.getFocusX(); and detector.getFocusY(). After this my view actually appear to scale more naturally)

Comment: @ricky Would you mind posting your final solution for future Googlers? Nice work!

Comment: yes, it's make sense)I will post my solution on the GitHub

Comment: @ricky where is the Github link? please share

Comment: @MikeOrtiz please Post your comment in code, I am not getting this. How should I grab the focus point of the scale,? please explain and share code

Comment: @MikeOrtiz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242187/how-to-zoom-list-item-from-center-of-pinch

Answer (score 1):

please add these lines

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
```

have a try with this

```
<com.android.app.core.view.ZoomableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</com.android.app.core.view.ZoomableListView>
```

Comment: thank's for answer but I meant that listview doesn't scroll before zooming

Comment: @Jitesh Upadhyay please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242187/how-to-zoom-list-item-from-center-of-pinch